# Вычесть дату из даты

Tags: php, дата, время

Как вычесть дату из даты?

Пробовал вот так:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i', strtotime($saled)));
$datetime2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i', strtotime($salee)));
$secs = $datetime2 - $datetime1;
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону библиотеки Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял, Вам нужно из одной даты отнять другую. Если так то попробуйте:

```
$diference = strtotime($salee) - strtotime($saled); // разница между двумя датами в секундах
$minutes = $diference / 60; // секунды в минутах
$hours = $diference / 3600; // секунды в часах
$days = $diference / 86400; // секунды в сутках
```

Comment: а как мне получить ответ в таком виде "Y-m-d h:i" ?

Comment: А Вам это точно нужно? :)) Просто смотрите если из текущей даты отнять дату прошлого года, то год полученной даты будет 1. Объясните подробнее зачем Вам это нужно, может быть если более правильные решения чем отнять дату.

Comment: мне нужно выводить оставшееся время и дней - от конечной даты отнять текущую

Comment: Количество секунд не позволяет корректно получить интервалы, начиная с месяцев. Количество суток получить почти можно(есть нюансы с переводами часов, високосными секундами и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

Создайте для каждой даты объект `DateTime`. Воспользуйтесь методом `DateTime::diff()` для получения объекта `DateInterval`, описывающего разность между датами.
Разность между двумя датами в неделях, днях, часах, минутах и секундах.

```
// 19:32:56, 10 мая 1965 года
$first = new DateTime("1965-05-10 7:32:56pm",
new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
// 4:29:11, 20 ноября 1962 года
$second = new DateTime("1962-11-20 4:29:11am",
new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$diff = $second->diff($first);
printf("The two dates have %d weeks, %s days, " .
"%d hours, %d minutes, and %d seconds " .
"elapsed between them.",
floor($diff->format('%a') / 7),
$diff->format('%a') % 7,
$diff->format('%h'),
$diff->format('%i'),
$diff->format('%s'));
```

Результат:

```
The two dates have 128 weeks, 6 days, 15 hours, 3 minutes, and 45 seconds
elapsed between them.
```

Также отвечая на вопрос в комментариях:
"как получить в формате "Y-m-d h:i" - функция date http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

```
$today = date("Y-m-d h:i");
```